# Move Database To Another Folder

Tags: database, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

How can I relocate database from one folder to another on the same server while the server is running?

Comment: Isn't this an admin question? Move to serverfault.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Domino Administrator has an option to move a database in background.

I never used it and i think it will create a copy of the original database and then delete the orgin.

I always move on os level: stop domino, mv file, start domino. It takes much more less time and space if on the same partition.

HTH.

Comment: An OS file copy maintains the copy as a Replica database of the original (ie: the same Replica-ID) - this may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without stopping the server.  Make sure all users are out of the database.

First, go to the console and type **drop users** (which drops all connections users have to the server.  Sounds bad, but it is like interrupting their network connections, and their Notes workstations are smart enough to reconnect).

Next type **dbcache flush**.  This clears any cache locks the server has on the specific NSF file.

Now (quickly) go to the file at the OS level (Windows Explorer, or whatever the equivalent is on your server) and move the file to the new folder.  If it doesn't work, you may need to repeat the dbcache flush feature a few times.  Sometimes the server takes control back again immediately, especially if someone reconnects to that NSF file.

Comment: Moving a NSF on the file level while the server is running is Russian roulette. Use adminp or the replica approach

Comment: Russian roulette is a bit harsh, but you're right there are dangers to consider.  Links to the database thankfully should work since they'll search the server by replicaID, but URLs would break if you are accessing via Domino.  If you can think of other dangers add them below.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new replica of the database in the new folder then once your happy that everything has replicated lock everyone out of the old one disallowing access in the ACL. In a few days you can remove the first replica, you can force everyone over to the new replica by doing a series of drop all's on the server console.

If users are in the database it won't make any difference but when they log out and try to get back in the server will simply redirect them to the replica in the new folder, it may mean a slight delay so switch over is best done out of hours.

Be careful to not lock yourself and other system admins out, and do not check the syncronise acl option!! It's also no longer a problem having multiple replicas of the same database on a server although out of habit I wouldn't leave the old one around to long.